# How to make a HTTP persistent connection with server using AFNetworking library

Tags: ios, http, keep-alive, afnetworking-2

Can anyone please point me in the right direction in making a HTTP persistent connection with server using `AFNetworking` library. I've already looked at the following code:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
AFRocketClient *client = [[AFRocketClient alloc] init];
[client SUBSCRIBE:@"/resources" usingBlock:^(NSArray *operations, NSError *error) {
for (AFJSONPatchOperation *operation in operations) {
    switch (operation.type) {
        case AFJSONAddOperationType:
            [resources addObject:operation.value];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
} error:nil];
```

from https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFRocketClient

Which I felt is not self explanatory???

Comment: did you read up on rocket? http://rocket.github.io this should clear things up...

Comment: Thanks Roman. Thats well explained! But unfortunately I was not able to make a live HTTP connection yet??  I have my previous code base implemented via ASIHTTPRequest by making a GET request and setting timeout as -1. But now Im trying to implement this via AFNetworking library.