# Does AFRocketClient work for POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, post, afnetworking

On a particular view controller of my app, the user pushes a button to invoke a REST POST request. The button is usually pushed several times. I'm using AFNetworking 2.0 to do this.

The lag time between the POST request and success callback is quite erratic. Sometimes it's < 1 second, while other times it's several seconds or more. I require the lag time to be as little as possible.

One possible reason for this is the TCP connection being closed and re-opened again repeatedly. Some Stackoverflow articles mention that iOS closes the connection if no request is sent after a few seconds. Indeed, when I used a NSTimer to constantly send POST requests every 2.5 seconds, the time lag is reduced to < 1 second.

But this seems like a crude way to do things, and I'm afraid the server side might get swamped with too many requests (the server here is actually a raspberry pi). Is there another way to do this? 
[HTTP Persistent Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326936/how-to-make-a-http-persistent-connection-with-server-using-afnetworking-library) mentions AFRocketClient, but I tried it with no success. Could it be that AFRocketClient is only for Server-Sent Events, whereas I am doing a "Client-Sent Event"? Or is my implementation of AFRocketClient wrong? Don't entirely understand the rocket code snippet.

Thanks in advance!

My code below:

```
    - (void)updateSpeed {

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"command": @"48",
                                 @"dat": @"0",};

    //Create instance of AFHTTPSessionManager and set response to default JSON
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    //Pass POST request

    [manager POST:@"submit" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

         self.status = responseObject;
         for (id key in self.status) {
         NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@ \n", key, [self.status objectForKey:key]);
         }
      [client SUBSCRIBE:@"submit" usingBlock:^(NSArray *operations, NSError *error) {
    for (AFJSONPatchOperation *operation in operations) {
        switch (operation.type) {
            case AFJSONAddOperationType:
                [resources addObject:operation.value];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
} error:nil];
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

    }];
}
```

[- AFRocketClient Github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFRocketClient)